# AWS IOT : Cannot Register with shadow

Tags: aws-iot

I have created a thing in AWS IoT called RasberryPi and I am trying to register with its shadow using the following code :

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');

var thingShadows = awsIot.thingShadow({
   keyPath: "./certs/private.pem.key",
   certPath: "./certs/certificate.pem.crt",
   caPath: "./certs/root-CA.crt",
   clientId: "RasberryPi1",
   region: "eu-west-1",
   port: "8883",
   debug: true
});

thingShadows.on('connect', function() {

    console.log('connected');

    thingShadows.register( 'RasberryPi1', function() {
        console.log('registered');
...
```

I successfully connect but I never register. That is, the second console.log statement never runs. Can anybody please advise on my mistake? I'm very new to AWS IoT and my mistake is probably very basic.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may be really confusing but it is because of docs. You are probably following examples like here: https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#thing-shadow-class

```
//
// After connecting to the AWS IoT platform, register interest in the
// Thing Shadow named 'RGBLedLamp'.
//
thingShadows.register( 'RGBLedLamp', function() {
    // Your code here
}
```

but when you read the docs here: https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#awsiotthingshadowregisterthingname-options-callback- you can see that the register function takes callback not as second argument but as **third**(!)

Just call it like this:

```
 thingShadows.register( 'RGBLedLamp', {}, function() {
    // Your code here
}
```

and it'll work like a charm